# Python how any consecutive series

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function able to tell how many series of consecutive strictly positive integers exist, the sum of which is equal to a given whole number

For example, for n = 100, the sum of the series 18,19,20,21,22 is 18 + 19 + 20 + 21 + 22 = 100. But how many such series exist whose sum is equal to n? For example, with n = 100, there are 3:

```
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
18, 19, 20, 21, 22
100
```

I'm am trying to create a function able to return those series and tell how much of them there are.

How do I code that ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework/interview problem. Have you written any code yet? If so, please post. What processes have you already tried?

Comment: Can you write this in pseudo-code, at least, and show you've done a bit of work on this problem?  For example, for a specific value of n, what is the maximum possible number of sequences you have to check?

Comment: It is. I first tried to get all consecutive elements like this

import itertools
import operator

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for L in range(0, len(mylist)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        print(subset)

It obviously didn't worked out...

Comment: Tip: you're looking for the sum of an arithmetic series, the formula for which is:

`n = 0.5 * (length_of_sequence)*(first_term + last_term)`

Which means:

`n = 0.5 * (last_term - first_term + 1) * (first_term + last_term)`

Comment: Could you edit the question with what you have so far? Especially if this is a homework or interview question, we don't really want to write the code for you, but rather help you learn how to write the code for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's forget about the code and think about how we could write the sequences in
a piece of paper. Because the numbers in a sequence **need to be consecutive**, that means that the numbers in a sequence of `n` elements whose sum is `N` **will
always be "around" `N/n`**.

If `N` is even then a sequence of two numbers will never exist. On the other hand, if `N` is odd then a sequence of two numbers always exists. Ex: For `N=101` we would have the sequence `50, 51`. It is always in the form `N//2, N//2 + 1`, where `//` is integer division as in Python.

For a sequence of 3 elements the sequence would need to `N/3 - 1, N/3, N/3 + 1`,
but it will only exist **if `N` is divisible by `3`**. In fact, for any odd `n` a
sequence of `n` elements exists in the form `N/n - n//2, ..., N/n -1, N/n, N/n + 1, ..., N/n + n//2` as long as `N` is divisible by `n`.

Ex: For `N=100` and
`n=5` you have that `100/5` is `20` and `n//2` is `2`, thus the sequence is
`20-2, 20-1, 20, 20+1, 20+2`.

For a sequence of 4 elements you would have `N//n - 1, N//n, N//n + 1, N//n +
2`. I'll let you think about when such sequence exists and the case for any even
`n`.

---

It is always useful to think about these kinds of problems without caring too much about the actual code and just sketch the solution in a piece of paper. Once you figure it out how to do it, then it shouldn't be hard to turn that into actual code. It will also be much easier to debug the code if you make some mistake, since you know what you are doing, instead of trying to figure it out how to do it while you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the amount of consecutive sums for that number. That being said, I've left it up to you to find what those sequences are. It should be relatively simple once you figure out the code! There are some hints in the comments on this post, and the code should be self-explanatory.

```
def sum_counter(x):
    #Written by Sam Carpenter on stackoverflow
    bottom = 1
    top = 1
    counter = 1
    while top < x:
        value = (top - bottom + 1)*(top + bottom)*0.5
        if value == x:
            counter += 1
            top += 1
            bottom += 1
        elif value > x:
            bottom += 1
        else: top += 1
    return counter
```

In the future, make sure that you work on the problem and post everything you have leading up to that. Additionally, if you need this code for homework, or an interview, or a challenge, or anything like that, please don't steal this code! It's important that you do that for yourself, or you miss all of the value. Make sure you understand this code.

Answer (score -1):

Please look at this solution to your problem. But it's weird that I could get only 2 consecutive numbers. Please give it a shot anyway.

```
def get_numbers(arr: List[int], num: int):
    start_index = 0
    count = 0
    sum_factor = 0
    result = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(arr):
        sum_factor += value
        if sum_factor < num:
            continue
        if sum_factor == num:
            result.append((start_index, idx))
        while sum_factor >= num:
            sum_factor -= arr[start_index]
            start_index += 1
            if sum_factor == num:
                result.append((start_index, idx))
    return [arr[a: b +1] for a, b in result]
```